# Is it possible to create UITableViewCells inside a for/in loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm calling a function in which i retrieve a `NSDictionary` with data that needs to be displayed in tableviewCells. Is it possible to call the method

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in another method?

Comment: Why? The table view will ask for cells when it needs them.

Comment: Because I hate to store the data in a separate Array and then load the data from that array into the cell again. It's just not neat.

Comment: @bdv How is that not neat? You can abstract the data from the view that way, which makes much more sense from a software architecture standpoint.

Comment: @bdv But that's how it works. You update your data model and the table view data source methods make use of the data model. You can't preload cells.

Comment: Thanks guys! just wanted to be sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly call any methods of `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`, but should only be done in cases of dire need. In a project of mine, I get specific (subclassed) cells which draw elements **not** in the `drawRect:` method, but in a `drawCell` method I have defined, for performance gains (preventing offscreen rendering, etc).

Unless your cells have special drawing needs, (resizing subviews, etc) you should let the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method do this work for you.

Still, if you want to explicitly get cells, you may do with:

```
[yourTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This will return you your cell. Mind you, it will execute all relevant code inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` including dequeueing, creation, and any other calls you have made in it.

`indexPath` passed here is an object of type `NSIndexPath`, and you may create one like this:

```
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:ROW_NUM inSection:SECTION_NUM];
```

Where, `ROW_NUM` is the is the row number inside the section, which is `SECTION_NUM`. For the first cell in the third section, the `indexPath` is:

```
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:2];//Since indices start at 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to call that one specific method inside another method. However, you can call `[self.tableView reloadData]` inside any methods. This call all the UITableView delegate methods which includes `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: Actually, it's trivial to call `cellForAtIndexPath` from another method. Of course it's wrong and pointless, but it is possible.